# transforming data frame with python

Tags: python-2.7

Let's assume that I have the following data frame in pandas:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/813YP.png)

and I want to transform it to the following:
[transformeddataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAfkG.png)

How can I do it?

I have tried doing transpose, pd.wide_to_long, pd.melt but they are throwing errors. I am new to this and need help please!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe that can be easily copied, such as by using `df.head().to_dict()`.

Comment: @Rawson I have attached the link to the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
df = (
    pd.read_csv("bmi.csv", index_col=0, header=[0,3], na_values="No data")
        .replace("\s+.+", "", regex=True).stack(0, dropna=False)
        .astype(float).reset_index(level=0, names="Country").pipe(
            lambda x: x.set_axis(x.index.str.split(".").str[0]))
        .groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), "Country"], sort=False).first()
        .reset_index(names=["Year", "Country"]).rename_axis(columns=None)
        .sort_values(by=["Country", "Year"], ascending=[True, False])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      Year      Country   Both sexes   Female   Male
0     2016  Afghanistan         23.0     23.7   22.3
1     2015  Afghanistan         22.9     23.6   22.3
2     2014  Afghanistan         22.8     23.5   22.2
3     2013  Afghanistan         22.8     23.4   22.1
4     2012  Afghanistan         22.7     23.3   22.0
...    ...          ...          ...      ...    ...
8143  1979     Zimbabwe         22.0     23.6   20.3
8144  1978     Zimbabwe         21.9     23.6   20.2
8145  1977     Zimbabwe         21.9     23.5   20.2
8146  1976     Zimbabwe         21.8     23.5   20.1
8147  1975     Zimbabwe         21.8     23.5   20.0

[8148 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Yes this works exactly how I want! Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to recreate the output dataframe from the initial pictured dataframe (the first few lines just recreate your dataframe).

```py
import pandas as pd
# recreating your starting dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\...\bmi.csv", index_col=0)
df = df.iloc[2:, :]  # drop first 2 rows to match your initial picture


# Change column names to just the year
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).str.split(".", n=1, expand=True)[0]
# and add the first row
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df.columns,
                                                df.iloc[0].str.lstrip())))
# then remove first row
df = df.iloc[1:]

# stack the first level of the MultiIndex column (year), and sort the index
df = df.stack(level=0).sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[True, False])

# in each column...
for col in df.columns:
    # ...extract the float at the start of the string (and convert to float)
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.